# Make Branch accessible after git fetch

Tags: git, fetch

Is there a way to make a branch directly accessible after a `git fetch` without `git checkout <newbranch>`?

If I use the `git fetch` command I want to see the new branches directly in the list shown after I use e.g. `git branch`.

Comment: No...it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "accessible" you mean visible in the list given by `git branch` then you can use the `-a` flag:

```
git branch -a
```

it will show all the branches including the remote tracking ones.

So if someone added `second_branch` to the remote repository, before running `git fetch` you might see:

```
%> git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/master
```

Then after the `git fetch` you might see:

```
%> git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/second_branch
```

If you only want to see the remote tracking branches there's also the `-r` option.